# Yesod other website resource

Tags: haskell, yesod

How can I define a resource which represents, for instance, http://www.yesodweb.com? I'd call it like this:

```
<a href=@{YesodHomePageR}>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with `#{}` interpolation:

```
let yesodHomePage = "http://yesodweb.com"

[hamlet| <a href="#{yesodHomePage}">]
```

But if you really want to use URL interpolation, you can create a route for it and use `redirect` in its handler:

```
redirect "http://yesodweb.com"
```